# Lines with 10 columns to be modified into lines with 3 columns

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, pattern-matching

I have a huge data file containing 10 columns per line. It must be rearranged such that it contains 3 columns per line. Can sed or awk or perl do this for me? For example, the following lines

```
 -6.222  -5.809  43.663   3.778  -5.809  43.663   7.784   5.483 -14.013   6.873
  5.197 -13.865   5.648  -0.107 -14.156   5.485  -1.058 -14.103  -0.809   7.565
-11.708  -1.157   6.740 -11.343  -0.687  -7.913 -15.833  -0.823  -8.865 -15.733
```

must become

```
 -6.222  -5.809  43.663 
  3.778  -5.809  43.663 
  7.784   5.483 -14.013 
  6.873   5.197 -13.865 
  5.648  -0.107 -14.156
  5.485  -1.058 -14.103
 -0.809   7.565 -11.708
 -1.157   6.740 -11.343
 -0.687  -7.913 -15.833
 -0.823  -8.865 -15.733
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a script that can do this for you, or a one-liner? Is the alignment important?

Comment: The alignment isn't important. I was looking for a script (which has been answered kindly by others), which I could modify to meet my needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternate solution using command line utilities [`tr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) and [`fold`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fold)

```
$ tr '\n' ' ' < file | fold -w24
 -6.222  -5.809  43.663
  3.778  -5.809  43.663
  7.784   5.483 -14.013
  6.873   5.197 -13.865
  5.648  -0.107 -14.156
  5.485  -1.058 -14.103
 -0.809   7.565 -11.708
 -1.157   6.740 -11.343
 -0.687  -7.913 -15.833
 -0.823  -8.865 -15.733
```

The replacement of newline with space is intentional to preserve formatting.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way that you could do it using awk:

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) printf "%s%s", $i, (++j%3==0 ? ORS : OFS) }' file
```

Goes through each field one by one and prints it followed by the Output Field Separator (which is a space by default), or the Output Record Separator (a newline) every 3 fields.

Instead of `%s`, you can use `%7.3f` to specify a fixed width floating point output, 7 characters long, with 3 decimal places. This will mean that the numbers are aligned (as they are in the question).

The above line can be turned into a script easily:

```
{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) printf "%s%s", $i, (++j%3==0 ? ORS : OFS) }
```

Save and run with `awk -f script.awk file`.

...although you could just use xargs:

```
xargs -n 3 < file
```

xargs is designed to build and execute command lines from the standard input stream. In this case, nothing is being executed (the arguments are effectively being `echo`ed) but the `-n` switch is useful as it specifies the maximum number of items to be read in at a time.

Comment: Added something to your idea: `xargs -n 3 < file | while IFS=" " read A B C; do printf "%7.3f %7.3f %7.3f\n" $A $B $C; done`

Comment: Thanks for the input but I think that it is preferable to use awk if alignment is required. I edited my answer and included your format specifier.

Comment: The `awk` variant will work well with GNU `awk`. In other `awk`'s such as BSD or Solaris, it will fail due to unparenthesised ternary operator. This will be more portable `awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) printf "%s%s", $i, (++j%3==0 ? ORS : OFS) }' file`

Comment: @jaypal I actually removed them in an edit! That's useful to know, thanks. I've replaced them.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Perl solution.

It simply keeps a buffer `@row` of values from the file that is topped up every time it fall below three elements.

While there are enough elements in the array they are formatted and printed three per line.

The `if` statement after the loop is to catch any spare values in case the number of fields in the file isn't a multiple of 3.

The program expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @row;

while (<>) {
  push @row, split;
  while (@row >= 3) {
    printf '%8.3f', $_ for splice @row, 0, 3;
    print "\n";
  }
}

if (@row) {
   printf '%8.3f', $_ for @row;
   print "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple Perl program that can achieve that :

(Edited version with some improvements suggested by @Miller)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Read the entiere file
while (<>) {
    chomp;               # remove the end-of-line
    push @_,split /\b /; # split the numbers around each first space
    while (@_ >= 3) {
        print join(' ',splice @_, 0, 3), "\n";
        }
}

print join(' ',splice @_, 0, 3), "\n" if (@_);
```

You can use it with the following command line :

```
perl to3cols.pl hugefile.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. Perl gives me the additional advantage of playing with the script to modify it more the way I wish.

Comment: This reads the entire file into an array, which may be okay if the *"huge"* data file isn't too big!

Comment: I totally agree. I just improved the script to take that into account

Comment: I'd considering using `split ' '` instead of `/\b /` because one can't guarantee there won't be trailing spaces on lines.

Comment: I assumed that the input data would match the samples given, where there is no trailing spaces, and where the numbers seem to be already aligned. Of course, this solution may be improved, and the Borodin's solution may also be correct, even if its output is not exactly the same as the one expected (some spaces are missing). For the same reason, a `split ' '` would work, but will produce incorrect indentations.

Comment: @Orabîg: Regarding the expected output, I think you have omitted the trailing space on the first four lines.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' 'NF{printf "%8s%s",$0,(++c%3?FS:"\n")}' file
  -6.222   -5.809   43.663
   3.778   -5.809   43.663
   7.784    5.483  -14.013
   6.873    5.197  -13.865
   5.648   -0.107  -14.156
   5.485   -1.058  -14.103
  -0.809    7.565  -11.708
  -1.157    6.740  -11.343
  -0.687   -7.913  -15.833
  -0.823   -8.865  -15.733
```